# Como colocar 0x0D 0x0A no fim de um arquivo txt

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho o final do código de meu arquivo txt abaixo e segundo o manual da receita, pede para que eu coloque os caracteres 0x0D 0x0A no fim do registo.

Como poderia fazer isso?

```
ATT01 = DETIM.ValidaATT(item.Cells["att"].Value.ToString()).PadRight(17, ' ');
ATT01 =   ATT01.Substring(0, ATT01Const);
Filler1 = Tamanho01.ToString().PadRight(2, ' ');
Filler1 = Filler1.Substring(0, Filler1const); //Acho que deveria ser colocado aqui mas não sei como!!
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [Esta tabela](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que você precisa é adicionar no final do seu arquivo a seguinte `string`:  `\r\n`

Comment: e o que faz o \r\n? Pula uma linha?

Comment: Sim, como se teclasse `ENTER`.